# What are the differences between defining a public URL when creating a new web application , and defining an alternative access mapping

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

If I want to create a new web application to be under a URL such as `http://companyname.intra`. So I found that I can do so when creating  a new web application, where I can define the Public URL to be `http://companyname.intra` , or I can define the web application to be under `http://servername:portnumber` and hen define an alternative access mapping for the `servername:prtnumber` to be `http://compnayname.intra`. So what are the differences between both approaches ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog will gives you a better understanding of AAM.

http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/03/a-guide-to-alternate-access-mappings-basics-in-sharepoint-2013/